# Injection proof

Tags: proof-writing

Prove that for any $A, B \subseteq X$ we have $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$, then $f$ is an injection.

I get stuck at the step where $f(w) = y = f(z)$, since I am trying to prove it is injective, I can't just say they're equal right?

Comment: This is neither about multisets nor injective modules, I edited the tags accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(w)=f(z)=y$, then you know that $f(\{w\}\cap \{z\})=f(\{w\})\cap f(\{z\})=\{y\}$. Since $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$, we conclude $\{w\}\cap\{z\}\ne\emptyset$, i.e. $w=z$.